# Installing SQL server 2005 and creating database during setup wizard in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have a c# application that which contains a database in SQL server 2005.
I wish to first install sql server 2005, create the database, tables in that database during run time i.e. during installation of my c# application. The setup wizard should install all this and then install my c# application.

I went through msdn walkthroughs but the solution is in visual basic.

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide more details

Comment: @Greg My c# application is for some sales application. whenever i create a setup of my application on any machine sql server 2005 should get installed first. My databases, tables should be installed second and then my c# application should be installed. How can this be done ?

Comment: Use silent installation method for sql server installation

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113480/SQL-Server-2008-R2-Unattended-Silent-Install

Answer (score 1):

After installation of your application, first check your DB on Login form / Start up form. If your DB not exists in DBMS, restore the back of your DB at run time.

Comment: Is there any way to handle that using runtime setup installation ?

Comment: The reason is it will everytime check in the try catch block on my startup form of c# application